# Missing Params on Post in Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm learning Ruby on Rails at the moment and we're making a blog app to learn about crud actions and such and I'm stuck on this create method in my controller not working as it does in the course. I'm having trouble the create method in this controller:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end
    def index
        @articles = Article.all
    end
    def new

    end
    def create
        @article = Article.new(params.require(:article).permit(:title, :description))
        @article.save
        redirect_to @article
    end

end
```

I get this error when trying to create an article:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in ArticlesController#create
param is missing or the value is empty: article
```

It seems to be getting hung up on the first line of the create method but I'm not sure why it doesn't think there's an article... Here's my new article view as well for further reference:

```
<h1>Create a new Article</h1>
<%= form_with scope: @article, url: articles_path, local: true do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :title %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :description %><br/>
        <%= f.text_area :description %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check whether your parameters coming under hash with key article like this -

{"article"=>{params}}

Also initiate Article object in new action.

You can redefine the params to permit like this:

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code. Instead, paste the code directly into your answer. That helps others to re-use your answer and makes it much more accessible.

Answer (score 2):

in controller new method create object

```
@article = Article.new
```

and in form HTML add one more option use method: "post"